# How do I add resources files to WIX project

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have switched to WiX version 3.5 for my installer. I have seen that for adding a file we need to define a `<Component>` entry for each file. This is OK for me.

My application is localized and have defined resource string entries for French and English. The build creates a satellite structure in the `/bin` folder.

Do I have to add that structure to WiX in a similar way as any other file or is there a more straight way?

Comment: If you're asking about the way to localize your installation, then WiX has its own way to do this. For instance, take a look at this article in tutorial: http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/dontcha-speak-english. BTW, reading tutorial is a good idea on its own.

Comment: I am not willing to get my installer as localized but trying to find the way how to get folder architecture created like en;fr,fr-FR known as satelite when you use different ressource string in the application. I try to add them in similar way as normal file but seems they are not created

Comment: I find it out, sateliite definition was in the wrong place in the wix file